# Troubles with ::MoveWindow - leaving blank space

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface, mfc

I am quite desperate to resolve this very annoying issue :(
I am trying to display a child window on parent window. Some time the window need to be resized. But for some reason, when I using MoveWindow function it leaves blank space on the top of the parent window. I would like to present a picture here but I can not post a picture.

Here is the code example:

```
HWND hwnd  // Comes from external function. Was defined as WS_CHILD previously
HWND hwndParent     = ::GetParent(hwnd);  
RECT parentRect     = {0,0,0,0};  
RECT childRect      = {0,0,0,0};  
::GetClientRect(hwndParent, &parentRect);  // Suppose it returns {0,0,600,300}  

BOOL ok = ::MoveWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, 600, 300, true);  
::GetClientRect(hwnd, &childRect);  // Will return {0,0,584,297}
```

WHY ?????

What am I doing wrong? Did I forgot some flags with window initialization?!

Comment: Should you be using getwindowrect instead, to account for the non-client area?

Comment: @Iron-Eagle: Do you redraw the parent window properly when it receives the WM_PAINT message?

Comment: I am skeptical of the part where you say "// suppose it returns ...". Why suppose anything?

Comment: Alex K: - How exactly will it help?  Alex - Yes, the redrawing is working.   tenfour - What I mean is that I give ::MoveWindow the same numbers I got from ::GetClientRect. The numbers themself are not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was WS_POPUP flag to the parent window.
Very strange. As far as I know it was not suppose to have such an effect.

Thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `GetClientRect`, use `GetWindowRect` and `MapWindowPoints(NULL,hwndParent,&parentRect,2)` to adjust it to the parent window coordinates. `GetWindowRect` will include the non-client area that `MoveWindow` requires.

**Edit:** If you want a window that doesn't have a non-client area so the window rect and the client rect are the same size, you need to trim the [window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czada357%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that you apply to the window. Avoid the WS_BORDER, WS_CAPTION, WS_DLGFRAME, WS_OVERLAPPED, WS_SIZEBOX, and WS_THICKFRAME styles.

Comment: Yes, but I am interested in client area.

Comment: It does not help.
Still, it looks like that: http://i32.fastpic.ru/big/2011/1016/39/9e4460be87c03499e8b183a130902d39.png

Comment: There is probably a little misunderstanding. The PARENT window should have simple windows style (Name, X-Button, Minimize button etc). And it has it. The problem is that not entire CLIENT-AREA is used. There is a blank space left inside CLIENT area. Please look at the picture. There is nothing at the grey area, the GetClientRect returns me certain size, but for some reason only PART of this size is used.

Comment: @Iron-Eagle, the reason the whole client area is not used is that the entire child window must fit within it, *including* any non-client borders that the child has. My advice was to make sure the child window doesn't have any styles that would create a non-client area; if you do it properly, GetClientRect and GetWindowRect will return the same size. Use Spy++ to verify the window styles.

Comment: Here is the SPY information. http://i32.fastpic.ru/big/2011/1017/a5/8a03484c94285c611367fb017a7e14a5.png
As you can see, for some reason, client area moved to (3, 64) instead of (0,0). Can you suggest why?

Comment: @Iron-Eagle, this is really a mystery now. Is there any chance that you're passing negative coordinates to MoveWindow? The client area of the child can't extend past the client area of the parent.

Comment: what do you mean? You can see in example, I am passing exactly the area I am getting from parent's ::GetClientRect, starting from (0,0). I can not understand why it is starting from (3,64).
Will Spy++ information from Parent Window help?

Answer (score 0):

`MoveWindow` updates window position, while `GetClientRect` gets a client-area part of the window, which does not have to be the same. If your window has non-client area, then everything is fine and works as expected.

If you are still under impression that child window does not fully cover parent's client area, then the spacing belongs to the child control/window, and you need to look for ways to remove it there (control flags, parameters etc).

Comment: Ok. That is exactly what I thought! It seems that there is a place left for other things like top menu and window border and there are some flags I need to adjust. But can you suggest me what flags?

Comment: It might be `WS_*` and `WS_EX_*` window style flags. It is 16 px wide and 3 px high only, so I assume these are sort of borders. Anyway you have not even mentioned what these controls are, some standard or custom, or third party controls? This leave too much space for guesswork.

Comment: I am sorry I do not fully understand you.
What controls do you mean?

Comment: You have two windows, a parent and a child. What are they, what sort of windows they are?

Comment: Here is the spy information of the child window:
http://i32.fastpic.ru/big/2011/1017/a5/8a03484c94285c611367fb017a7e14a5.png

Comment: Before - the window has its client area span to full window size, after - it shrunk client area to leave space for sort of borders/captions. You are dealing with child window which chose to leave the spacing area. Why? It depends on this window, its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`MoveWindow` operates on window coordinates -- including non-client area (borders, title bar, etc).

`GetClientRect` gets the area of the client portion of the window, ignoring borders, title bar, etc.

This is where the mismatch is. If you want to `MoveWindow` to a desired *client* size, you need to just [`AdjustWindowRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to try and predict what to pass into `MoveWindow`. Note that it's not always possible, and not always accurate. For example minimum / maximum sizes of windows, menus (which can wrap to multiple lines), etc.

Comment: But that is exactly the problem. I see a blank field on top of the window in ADDITION to the top bar, meaning that there is something else in the window that is treated like area that already taken by something and therefore, can not be used. And I can not understand what it is. Suppose even AdjustWindowRect will set the rect to {0,0,584,287} from {0,0,600,300}. It still leaves the question - why?

Comment: It's because the child window has a non-client area. What are the window styles of the child window? Screenshots are helpful too. What confuses me about your observation is "blank space on top of parent window". Even if the rect is smaller, the size would not have anything to do with the top of the window, only the bottom / right. It's pretty easy to just specify `(0,0)` as top/left coordinates.

Comment: Well, here is the screenshot: http://i32.fastpic.ru/big/2011/1016/39/9e4460be87c03499e8b183a130902d39.png   
As for window styles - here they are WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CHILD. I tried to play with them, by the way, it did not help.
As for the rest - this is exactly the problem I am trying to solve :)

Comment: When you set the position of the child window, your top/left coords should just be (0,0) you realize? MoveWindow top/left is relative to the parent's client window area.

Comment: Well, of course I realize. Please note that my coordinates indeed (0.0) (See the code in original question). The problem, however is - why it does not placed at (0,0)?

Comment: I think you just need to paste actual code to reproduce the problem. The code you gave is not your real code, so I can only make guesses about what the real problem is. If you specify (0,0) top left coords, and it's not being placed there, you seem to have some issue probably unrelated to this call. Maybe it's being obscured by another window. Maybe the parent window is giving wacky coords in WM_NCCALCSIZE. One can only guess.

Comment: This is the actual code, not complete of course. Here is the spy information of the child window before and after resize:
http://i32.fastpic.ru/big/2011/1017/a5/8a03484c94285c611367fb017a7e14a5.png